# Request reopen this question

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[My company is only offering training to people who are not white males due to diversity push. They have openly told us this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/182828/my-company-is-only-offering-training-to-people-who-are-not-white-males-due-to-di)

There is merit in this question, and it has four upvotes so far.

I am on a diversity team and I can compare and contrast Diversity done right, and done wrong.  It is answerable, if anything, it should be labeled as controversial, if nothing else.

This is also currently relevant due to the reports coming out from ESPN about this very thing

Comment: I closed it because it posed a rhetorical question and a legal one, everything else in it seemed ranty or incomplete at best. Up to the community if they want to reopen it.

Comment: I think we should avoid rants about diversity, affirmative action, "well that's discrimination against me", "what about *my* group", etc. I worry that it's an endless rabbit hole with no real solution, as evidenced by the comments. Perhaps there should be a different StackExchange forum for debating such issues. There could be good advice if the question was how to create an effective diversity program, but that's not what this question is about. It saddens me that this was re-opened, and 99% of the time I am in favor of keeping questions open.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I was hoping for a compassionate, level-headed answer that doesn't stoke flames of outrage when I voted to reopen, and Dan Romik's answer (especially the first and third numbered points) is a good one in my opinion. Rightly or wrongly, the OP is describing a real workplace situation that many would need help with.

Comment: @PlayerOne - the last "Extra" paragraph makes it clear to me that this isn't a real question, but rather a rant looking for amiright responses. I wish we wouldn't encourage this. There are forums where debating the fairness of affirmative action and diversity programs is appropriate. This isn't one of them.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The bool being named is a best seller, the author is being paid to speak at business conferences, and IMO counter productive to diversity efforts.  This is a real thing.

Comment: @PlayerOne I have put a bounty on that one.  I'm planning to award a bounty to Dan's answer

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter - I know the book. I understand your feelings on diversity. IMHO, discussing the merits of the book and arguments about the proper way to look at diversity belong elsewhere.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm of two minds on this, and maybe an edit of that last paragraph could help, but I am going to delete my answer and award the bounty

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Diversity is a touchy subject with me.  I have had a very tough time fighting for every inch of what I have and have been called everything from retard to actual physical abuse for my disabilities.  I have a bit of a knee jerk reaction to being called "privileged".  I like my company's approach because they avoid the whataboutisms.  I'm going to avoid future discussions on this topic until and unless I can do so without getting so angry.  Joe, I always value your opinion/input, even though it doesn't always sin in right away

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter - glad to hear your work on your company's diversity team is going well and that you like their approach. It's an extremely important subject.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes, it is important.  Their approach is that every voice should be heard and every need should be addressed,  I can't articulate it well, but it is inclusive instead of exclusive, it's about empowerment and engagement instead of victimhood, and there are people on the teams themselves are actually diverse.